# /net core 5 and application insights not receiving logTrace

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-application-insights

I have added the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package to my project. From there I registered application insights into my Startup.cs file and used it via Dependency injection in my controller. I receive all log information that was automatically generated, though cannot see my custom message. If anyone has any pointers, I would appreciate it!

My Csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Edaily.API</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Edailt.API.Data\Edaily.API.Data.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Edaily.API.Business\Edaily.API.Business.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My Startup.cs file

```
using Edaily.API.Data;
using Edaily.API.Implementation;
using Edaily.API.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Edaily.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<EdailyDbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<IClassesService, ClassService>();

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(o => { o.InstrumentationKey = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]; });

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Edaily.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Edaily.API v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My controller

```
using Edaily.API.Business.DTO;
using Edaily.API.Implementation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Edaily.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClassesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IClassesService classesService;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public ClassesController(IClassesService classesService, ILogger<ClassesController> logger)
        {
            this.classesService = classesService;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllClasses()
        {
            try
            {
                List<ClassViewModel> classViewModel = await classesService.GetAllClasses();
                logger.LogTrace("We hit the get all classes endpoint");
                return Ok(classViewModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Ilogger logs of Warning or higher severity is logged by default in ApplicationInsights. You may change `LogTrace` to `LogWarning` to see the traces in ApplicationInsights.
Alternately, you can change the filter rules, to include Trace level logs to application insights - see doc here for that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson

Comment: Where are the ILogger trace/debug etc. calls stored in App Insights? I believe I'm doing everything right but I can't find my logger message anywhere.

Comment: TraceTelemetry table. (Or ExceptionTelemetry table, if there is an Exception passed to ILogger)